# single page PDF but actually multi pages; how to convert?

Tags: pdf, multipage

I have a user manual PDF that every PDF viewer I've tried (acroread, okular, evince, Sumatra) thinks is a single page; but in fact it's multiple pages.

I've tried pdftk and acroread, and converting to Postscript.    How can I convert this PDF to a multipage PDF?  Open source solutions preferred.

The PDF is available here:  https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0754/2600/5314/files/T6.pdf

Comment: What makes you think it's multiple pages ? You should share the PDF file it's not really going to be possible for anyone to offer any suggestions without seeing the file.